Does Echo's "random Boon from the previous night" include Boons from the Pitch Black Stone?
The description for Echo's "Boon Boon Boon" gift says "Gain a random Boon from the previous night". Does "previous night" include attempts made with the Chaos Trials in the Pitch Black Stone?
Some of the Trials come with extremely rare and powerful boons. However, since you can't replay trials once they are completed, I haven't been able to test if this works.

In the current state of the game, it is possible. Any boon given automatically at the start of a Chaos Trial and all those obtained after can be obtained during the following Night if encountering Echo and picking up Boon Boon Boon.
